# Help with deciphering a specific statistical explanation

Tags: p-value

The replication fallacy is *the belief an obtained p value implies a probability of 1 – pvalue that an exact replication of the same experiment would lead to a significant result.*

In his "Mindless Statistics" article from 2004 Gigerenzer says that answering the following statement to be true (for a study where the p-value=0.01) amounts to the replication fallacy :

> **You have a reliable experimental finding in the sense that if, hypothetically, the experiment were repeated a great number of times,
> you would obtain a significant result on 99% of occasions**

Furthermore, he says that

> Here, p = 1% is taken to imply that such significant data would
> reappear in 99% of the repetitions. **The statement could be made only if
> one knew that the null hypothesis was true.** In formal terms, p(D|H0)
> is confused with 1 − p(D)

However, I think that if one knew that the null hypothesis was true, the statement would **not** be true. If H0 is true, then the probability of replicating such (or more extreme) results is 0.01, not 0.99. If H0 is true, then it is only by rare chance that we can get significant results.

If H0 is false, then that statement would still not be true, as the probability of getting significant results would depend on the power of the specific study. So the replication fallacy is false regardless of whether H0 is known to be true/false.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Pr(replication) = Pr(an independent dataset leads to a new p < 0.05 given the unknown true effect size) = an unknowable quantity in one sense.  Bayesian thinking, which uses observables, would lead to a totally different attack on the problem.

Comment: *"you would obtain a significant result on 99% of occasions"* what is described here is the power of the experiment. But there is not so much context to see whether this statement is confusing p-values with power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this statement makes no sense. It sounds like a moment of confusion for the author.

There have been attempts to derive the probability of replication for significant results, e.g. [Killeen (2005)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-rep), but they are doomed to failure as long as we don't know the true effect size and can only estimate it, per the criticisms of Killeen's article.